# c++ inheritance, constructor real caller

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have class A:

```
class A
{
    A(const String& name)
    {
        doSomething1();
    }
}
```

and I have also class B

```
class B : A
{
    B(const String& name): A(name)
    {
        doSomething2();
    }
}
```

So if I call B() it will call also A() and it will result with 2x calls doSomething().
Is there any way how to discover in A`s constructor that it is called directly like: A() and when indirectly: B() ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Well ok, it is not the same method doSomething() it is more like doSomething1() and doSomething2() but I want call the most outside function so if A has doSomething1() and B doSomething2(), after call B() I want to execute just doSomething2()

Comment: Without hacks, no. The design's wrong, I guess.

Comment: Don't fight the type system. Make it work *for* you.

Comment: I have the feeling you're asking for a XY-problem, if not just meant as an academic question.

Comment: If you want `doSomething` to be called exactly once, why not to throw away the call in `B()`?

Comment: You can add a protected constructor that's called from `B`. To ensure `B` calls this constructor and not the public one, make the public one (`A::A()`) private and provide a factory function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there's no way to discover from a base class if the object you're referring to is of a derived type.

Anyway your design is most likely flawed, something like this could also work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(const string& name)
    {
        doSomethingFromA();
    }

    void doSomethingFromA() {
        cout << "called from A" << endl;
    };
protected:
   A(const string& name, bool fromB)
   {
       doSomethingFromB();
   }

   void doSomethingFromB() {
        cout << "called from B" << endl;
    };
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    B(const string& name): A(name, true)
    {
    }

};


int main() {

    A obj1("str");

    B obj2("str");

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/jj8Df1

by exploiting the visibility of constructors you might pass additional info to the base class. Otherwise I'd advice using a slightly modified [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that renders your base class aware of the object itself (they become an entire different entity).

Comment: thanks I am aware of first option which you described in code and probably it will the way how I implement it. the problem is that I am adding something to the existing project, which has cca 5000 files and I can do just changes which will not cause needs to recompile projects written with that code.... but if I use default parameter value it should everything work just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You could have two overloads of `doSomething` as follow but...

```
void doSomething(A*);
void doSomething(B*);
```

And on the call site you do:

```
doSomething(this);
```

(`this` is either `A*` or `B*` so it will call the appropriate function.)

```
class A
{
    A(const String& name)
    {
        doSomething(this);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    B(const String& name): A(name)
    {
        doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

**But**, as other said in the comment, you have a design issue!